# Asked that he be careful vs. Ask him to be careful

Tags: meaning

I understand that the sentence

> I asked him to be careful.

is indirect speech and

> I asked *that* he be careful.

is subjunctive. What I don't understand is if there is any differences between them in meaning. When I say either of these sentences what comes to a native speaker's mind.

Are there any differences in meaning? Can I use each interchangeably? When does a native speaker tend to use either of these sentences?

Comment: In "I asked that he be careful." it is unclear who was asked.

Comment: I edited your question according to what I think you intended. "that" in the second example is not optional. You can undo edits if I am wrong.

Comment: The subjunctive is used to emphasize urgency or importance: I asked that he **be** careful.

Comment: @user3169 thanks for the edition. I thought it's optional. I wasn't really sure I just figured because _that_ is not the subject of the next clause it might be optional.

Comment: I upvoted both answers because I think both contributed to my understanding of the issue.

Comment: I think the subjunctive is not as far removed from the raw admonition as the statement *I asked him to be careful*, which is a statement about an admonition rather than a recasting of the admonition.

Comment: @TRomano if i understand correctly, you see the sentence with the subjunctive as a 'recasting of the admonition'; so you don't see really a difference between the function either of these sentences represents. Given the same context, they actually mean the same. Am i right?

Comment: The phrase **mean the same** is so difficult. They are the same color, different hues.

Answer (score 2):

Your two sentences can have slightly different meanings

> I asked him to be careful.
>   *I asked him to be careful on the drive home because it was snowing.*

can have the meaning that "he" be careful for himself "that he take care of himself"

> I asked *that* he be careful.
>   *I asked that he be careful moving the furniture around the house*

might usually be said with regard to "him" taking care when doing something with more regard to the environment round "him".

Comment: Is it OK if I interpret _I asked that he be careful_ as a **form of indirect speech** in which the importance or urgency of the statement is emphasized? In other words, I was emotionally more concerned. Does it give you as a native speaker such an implication?

Answer (score 2):

> I asked him to be careful.

This implies that you asked the person directly to be careful.

> I asked that he be careful.

This implies that you asked indirectly, through a supervisor for example, that the person be careful.  But this is ambiguous so the speaker can mean he spoke to the person directly.