# What does this BE mean in this sentence?

Tags: syntax

> When Valentine’s actions were discovered, Claudius ordered that he **be** put to death.

I don't know why there's a be there, anyone can help me with that?
Does it have anything to do with the verb *order*? Say, after *order* one should use the bare infinite?

I don't wanna guess anymore, somebody help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asked that he be careful vs. Ask him to be careful.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119348/asked-that-he-be-careful-vs-ask-him-to-be-careful) Also [I'm unclear about why we use 'to be' in these expressions of preference.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/243833/) And [require that X be used VS. require X to be used.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46831/) And [What does "that it be" mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/239968/what-does-that-it-be-mean) And more.

Answer (score 3):

*Be* is ***present subjunctive***:

> The subjunctive is most noticeable with the common but grammatically complicated verb ***be***. *In the present subjunctive, **be** staunchly remains **be** instead of changing to **am, are,** or **is** according to its subject*. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/getting-in-the-subjunctive-mood))

It is triggered by the verb ***ordered***:

> The other uncontroversial use is in sentences like the formal and often performative
>
> > I demand that the fabulous cat be compelled to present himself during my visit.
>
> We see that use following such verbs as ***ask, demand, propose, suggest***, and ***recommend*** [you can safely include ***order*** here], and after such phrases as ***it is advisable*** and ***it is necessary***.

Answer (score 2):

It is the usual copular verb, in a rather strange form.

This is a subjunctive passive construction - rather rare. The fact that "put" is an irregular verb also hides the passive construction.

> The executioner puts the prisoner to death.  / Active

> The prisoner is put to death (by the executioner)  / This is passive is+ past participle. The past participle of "put" is "put" (unchanged)

> The King ordered that the executioner put the prisoner to death / Subjunctive. Note "he put" not "he puts" in the subjunctive.

> The King ordered that the prisoner be put to death / Subjunctive and passive.

It might be clearer with a verb that has a distinct past participle:

> The king ordered that the prisoner be forgiven.